# Need to pass a compressed image for encryption in Android

Tags: android, compression

We are building an application which picks an image from the gallery displays it in imageView. When the encrypt button is pressed it is passed to a java class where it gets encrypted and is stored in the memory. I want to compress the image before encrypting. I am using Bitmap.scaledimage but I dont know exactly where to add it

Code for picking the image:

```
  public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Intent i= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i,SELECTED_PICTURE);
    }
    });
```

code for displaying the image:

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode)
    {
    case SELECTED_PICTURE:
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {

            Uri uri= data.getData();
            String[]projection= {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};                                                                   
            Cursor cursor= getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex= cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
            filePath= cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath));
            }
        break;
```

code for encrypting:

```
one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{
                blowfish encryptFile = new blowfish("thisismypassword");
                //destpath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+nameoffolder;
                destpath= x.getPath()+nameoffolder;
                //destpath="/storage/sdcard/test";
                encryptFile.encrypt(filePath,destpath);
                Toast.makeText(Image.this,
                        "Done encrypting..yey..",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(Image.this, e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();System.out.println("sells");
            }
        }
    });
```

File x is declared like this:

```
final File x=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),File.separator+"Image");
    x.mkdirs();
```

FilePath is string.

I want to know where I can add the image compression (what part of the code). Image compression we need bitmap but throughout I am working with uri, files and string for storing and displaying.

Comment: You are encrypting a .jpg file (in filePath). Why do you want to compress a .jpg file? That brings nothing.

Comment: We just want to reduce the size of the image while storing. Thanks for replying. There is also decrypt function which decrypts the image. I have not put up the code. We want the decrypted image to be of compressed format so as to save the size

Comment: What is the problem exactly. Code to load a jpg in a Bitmap and then change the resolution (widthxheight) has been posted many times on this site. `We want the decrypted image to be of compressed format so as to save the size `. Sorry but i do not understand where you are talking about.

Comment: Okk sorry I am not clear. We want the decrypted/encrypted image to be compressed so that the space that the image occupies is reduced. We want to compress and then encrypt the image. We are not sure where and what compression code to add. Hope I am clear now

Comment: So i was talking about resizing and you keep speaking about compressing. Would that be any different then resizing? I said before that a jpg cannot be compressed as it is already as compressed as can be. Zipping will not make a smaller file. I do not understand what you mean by compressing...

Comment: Why are you talking about the space that the image occupies instead of the size of a file you want to store. You will store a file isnt it?

Comment: Can blowfish encrypt a byte array?

Comment: Okk now I got you. Ya I need to resize it. Ya I am going to store the file. I need the size of the file to be reduced. Ya blowfish encrypts byte array

Comment: Then use BitmapFactory.decodeFile with an options parameter to scale down the resolution for instance four times. Then compress the bitmap as JPG  to a byte output stream and convert that to byte array. The byte array now contains the resized jpg. Then encrypt the byte array.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(String uri, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    Bitmap bm = null;

    try{
        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(uri)), null, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(uri)), null, options);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return bm;
}

public int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

might be like this. may i see your full coding? i need your encrypt and decrypt part.

Comment: Ya at end implemented my code in the above way. Thank you